# Bluetooth keyboard paired and connected but can't type anything

Tags: debian, keyboard, bluetooth

I have 3 boot on my laptop, but the problem occur when I use Zorin OS, an OS that based on Ubuntu 20. I have already used this bluetooth keyboard for a while now. Normally when I use this keyboard on Garuda OS or Windows, it connected automatically if I have used it on the same OS before. For example if I use Windows, shutdown, open it again, open Windows, it will connect automatically. But if I use Windows, shutdown, open it again, and choose Garuda for example, it need to be pair again. I need to forget the bluetooth and pair it again. Normally the bluetooth ask for 6 key code that I need to type for the pairing.

Now, on Zorin it's not normal. I need to pair it again every time I use Zorin, even if I already used Zorin before. But it never asked for 6 digit key.

Today I want to connect the keyboard, like I always do everyday, but I can't connect it today. To be specific, I can connect it, but I can't type with it. I try to restart my laptop but it's the same. I try to boot with Windows and Garuda OS, but the keyboard works on those two. It seems like a succesfull connection from the gui, but I can't type.

[image]

I try using terminal to connect:

```
lockrr@lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB:~$ sudo hciconfig  hci0 down
lockrr@lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB:~$ sudo hciconfig  hci0 up
lockrr@lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB:~$ sudo hciconfig  hci0 reset
lockrr@lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# devices
Device EC:2E:98:61:78:2C LAPTOP-UTURCPFT
Device 5B:E7:23:A2:0C:C7 5B-E7-23-A2-0C-C7
Device 74:60:9A:61:3A:75 74-60-9A-61-3A-75
Device 6D:5E:DC:CC:2D:76 6D-5E-DC-CC-2D-76
Device F0:B0:40:89:C1:82 MiTVStick
Device 41:42:E5:85:B4:07 SOUNDBOX LITE
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 58:00:E3:CF:1B:AA Discovering: yes
[CHG] Device 6D:5E:DC:CC:2D:76 RSSI: -69
[CHG] Device 6D:5E:DC:CC:2D:76 TxPower: 12
[NEW] Device 34:88:5D:39:97:F5 Logitech Keyboard K480
[CHG] Device EC:2E:98:61:78:2C RSSI: -75
[CHG] Device 74:60:9A:61:3A:75 RSSI: -67
[CHG] Device 5B:E7:23:A2:0C:C7 RSSI: -79
[CHG] Device 5B:E7:23:A2:0C:C7 TxPower: 8
[NEW] Device 4F:2E:44:30:09:E0 4F-2E-44-30-09-E0
[bluetooth]# pair 34:88:5D:39:97:F5
Attempting to pair with 34:88:5D:39:97:F5
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists
[bluetooth]# trust 34:88:5D:39:97:F5
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:39:97:F5 Trusted: yes
Changing 34:88:5D:39:97:F5 trust succeeded
[CHG] Device EC:2E:98:61:78:2C TxPower: 10
[CHG] Device F0:B0:40:89:C1:82 RSSI: -72
[CHG] Device 74:60:9A:61:3A:75 RSSI: -75
[bluetooth]# connect 34:88:5D:39:97:F5
Attempting to connect to 34:88:5D:39:97:F5
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:39:97:F5 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:39:97:F5 Modalias: usb:v046DpB330d2800
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:39:97:F5 UUIDs: 00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:39:97:F5 UUIDs: 00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:39:97:F5 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:39:97:F5 ServicesResolved: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 74:60:9A:61:3A:75 RSSI: -67
[CHG] Device 74:60:9A:61:3A:75 RSSI: -76
[CHG] Device 74:60:9A:61:3A:75 RSSI: -66
[CHG] Device 6D:5E:DC:CC:2D:76 RSSI: -77
[CHG] Device 74:60:9A:61:3A:75 RSSI: -74
[NEW] Device EC:2E:98:89:C1:82 EC-2E-98-89-C1-82
[Logitech Keyboard K480]#
```

seems like a success to me, but I still can't type. I suspect something block it, so I check with rfkill, but nothing:

```
lockrr@lockrr-Lenovo-YOGA-910-13IKB:~$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. My devices need legacy pairing so I need 6 digit pin to be typed on my keyboard, but my Bluetooth manager doesn't support this. I don't see the 6 digit pin. I don't know how I can connect the keyboard before, but what I know is somehow it connected.

I fix the problem by connecting with terminal. I use `bluetoothctl` to access the bluetooth. Then I list my mac addr, and pair it manually using

```
pair <<MAC_ADDR>>
connect <<MAC_ADDR>>
```

When I execute this, bluetooth ask for 6 digit pin, and I can access it using terminal.